# Solr: SimplePostTool not found error using quick start guide

Tags: java, solr, solr9, solr-9.3.0

I am learning Solr and using the quick start guide. When posting the example documents to the Solr core using the command:

```
java -jar -Dc=techproducts example/exampledocs/post.jar *.xml
```

I get those errors:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool
```

My Java version is JDK 11 and my Solr version is 9.3.0.

I am unable to figure out why I am getting those. I don't have multiple instances of Java installed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I tried the same command with Solr 9.1.1 and got no issue at all. Is this error only related to 9.3.0? Anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: What's the link to the file that you downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you downloaded the correct version on Solr (**Binary**) - https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/solr/solr/9.3.0/solr-9.3.0.tgz?action=download

There is a chance that you downloaded a **Source** release.

Comment: I tried with Binary but the same issue for 9.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem.

There are 'SimplePostToolxxx.class' files in 9.2.1.
example\exampledocs\post\org\apache\solr\util

But there is no such .class files in 9.3.0. Maybe this is the reason.

We may use SimplePostTool in 9.2.1 temporarily.

Comment: I agree with you, I tried both source and Binary for 9.3.0 the same issue. I am sticking with 9.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the post.jar is not complete anymore.

Try:

java -cp server\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\solr-core-9.3.0.jar org.apache.solr.cli.SimplePostTool -h